# OpenLayers with Yandex layer position issue

Tags: openlayers-2

I am kind of new for openlayers and I am working on a project that have many different layers.
one of this layer is Yandex, I added this layer few days ago and it seems to work fine, untill QA :) discovered that when you switch from this layer to another it not position the same as the other layer, I added this layer base on the following article (couldn't find anything else that show how to add the Yandex)
http://xbb.uz/openlayers/i-Yandex.Maps

when I have lines layer on the map and change the base layer from google, bing or any other layer to yandex the lines or the yandex layer are not positioned right.
YANDEX layer
[image]

OPEN STREET MAP LAYER
[image]

Comment: I am also trying to put a Yandex layer on OpenLayers. Did you solve it? It is something to do with the projections but I cannot find a solution anywhere. My code is: function yandex_getTileURL(bounds) { var r = this.map.getResolution(); var maxExt = (this.maxExtent) ? this.maxExtent : YaBounds; var w = (this.tileSize) ? this.tileSize.w : 256; var h = (this.tileSize) ? this.tileSize.h : 256; var x = Math.round((bounds.left - maxExt.left)/(r * w)); var y = Math.round((maxExt.top - bounds.top)/(r * h)); var z = this.map.getZoom(); var lim = Math.pow(2, z); if (y <0>= lim) { return OpenLayers.Util

Comment: No I still got no solution for it. I am working on finding a solution for it and I will update this post as soon as I will find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the projection there is not correct.

By common experience Yandex maps are in [EPSG:3395](http://epsg.io/3395), but Openlayers cannot handle it by itself. You'd need also to include [proj4.js](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js), then define a projection somethere:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:3395', '+proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +no_defs')
```

also

```
maxExtent: [-20037508.342789248, -20037508.342789248, 20037508.342789248, 20037508.342789248],
```

BTW there is a type in the code:

> if (y <0>= lim) {